# Play Framework: "Action not found" error for GET route after AJAX call to PUT/POST

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, playframework-2.0, url-routing

I'm in the process of adding some AJAX functionality to my Play application, following instructions provided by steps 5 ([Adding some AJAX actions](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGuide5)) and 6 ([Invoking actions from Javascript](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGuide6)) of the Zentask tutorial for Play Java.

My current setup for triggering a specific action when a `<button>` is clicked is as follows:

#### routes

```
PUT     /resources/:name/description controllers.Application.updateDescription(name: String)
...
GET     /assets/js/routes            controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()
...
```

#### Application.java

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
        response().setContentType("text/javascript");
        return ok(
            Routes.javascriptRouter(
                "jsRoutes",
                controllers.routes.javascript.Application.updateDescription()));
    }

...

    public static Promise<Result> updateDescription(String name) { ... }

}
```

#### main.scala.html

```
<script src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes()" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

#### app.js

```
...
button.on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    resourceName = "foo";
    route = jsRoutes.controllers.Application.updateDescription(resourceName);
    newDescription = "bar";
    $.ajax({
        url: route.url,
        type: route.type,
        data: { "description": newDescription },
        success: function(res) {
          alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
    });
});
```

---

While this works (I get a "Success" alert every time I click the button), looking at console output in Firefox developer tools I noticed that after the `PUT` request is executed, Play seems to be executing a separate `GET` request to the same URL: The console displays a line saying "no element found", and when I click on the corresponding link, a new window containing the source of a regular "Action not found" page opens. This page (correctly) states that no corresponding action could be found "For request `GET /resources/foo/description`" and lists all routes I have currently defined. This behavior persists when I change the HTTP method from `PUT` to `POST`.

**My question is:** Why is Play complaining about a missing action that I am never triggering? How can I keep it from checking for this action?

Comment: Do you get the same console output in Chrome? Could be firefox prefetching URLS.

Comment: @rufio86 Just tried Chromium and I'm not getting any warnings. Want to post your comment as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get the same console output in Chrome? Could be firefox prefetching URLS.